# Pass a Parameter to Another Function and Into innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, parameter-passing

I've built my own lightbox, and it's working rather well. I built my own because I needed it to be without a framework, and also work well within a game I'm building. However, I've run into a problem I'm fairly certain is simple, but proving rather vexing to me. The issue I'm having is taking the parameter "slideName" and passing it through to the "fillRightButton()" function.

```js
var createSlidebox = function(cancelButton, bannerImg, slideName) {
 fillRightButton("nextSlide",slideName);
};
```

Here's a portion of that function:

```js
var fillRightButton = function(rightButtonType, rightDestination) {

  if (rightButtonType === "nextSlide") {
    document.getElementById("lightbox_fright").innerHTML = '<a onclick="changeSlide(' + rightDestination + ')">Next</a>';
  }
}
```

The "fillRightButton()" function performs fine when it is called directly, and this code works if you put the parameter in directly:

```js
var createSlidebox = function(cancelButton, bannerImg, slideName) {
  fillRightButton("nextSlide", "mySlideName");
};
```

However, without the quotes it renders as:

```js
<a onclick="changeSlide([object Object])">Next</a>
```

with a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" JS error. How would I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use data attribute to store the object using jQuery, in function call

```
var fillRightButton = function(rightButtonType, rightDestination) {
  if (rightButtonType === "nextSlide") {
    document.getElementById("lightbox_fright").innerHTML = '';
    // document.getElementById("lightbox_fright").innerHTML = '<a onclick="changeSlide( $(this).data('dest') )">Next</a>';
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a['data-dest'] = rightDestination;
    a.onclick=function(){changeSlide( this['data-dest']); }
    a.innerHTML = 'Next';
    document.getElementById("lightbox_fright").appendChild(a);
    //document.getElementById('lightbox_fright > a').data({'dest':rightDestination});
  }
}
```

use jQuery if not already included

PS updated w/o jQuery please give it a try let me know if it works, recommend using jQuery though

Comment: Hello joyBlanks, appreciate it but I'm trying to avoid using any frameworks.

Comment: @RGStrat check if it works. updated the code. I am unable to get a snippet as I dont have the full code/fiddle

Comment: Thanks, works great! I'd considered creating the element but couldn't figure out if it would benefit me getting that data in there. Thanks again!